# Why I get totally different color after rendering a picture

Tags: rendering

I'm using blender for 10 days only so trying to follow the youtube chair tutorial, created everything I like but after rendering my back wall is blue instead of dark grey. What could cause this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: in the Outliner, click on the funnel icon, click on the camera icon (Disable in Renders) in order to see if you didn't make an object visible in render

Comment: we could clearly find the error if you could provide the .blend file....with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Tried to "Disable in renders", didn't help. Uploaded blend file

Comment: I guess I just found the other plane which is blue but it was hidden this was a problem, didn't expect a hidden file will render. Thanks